# Submitting new alter field

Tags: 8, webforms

I created a select/dropdown list and it works:

```
function hook_form_hook_ID_alter(&$form){
  $term_data = array(....) //array of key => values

  $form['elements']['location']['medical_name'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#title' => t('Medical Area'),
    '#options' => $term_data,
    '#empty_option' => t('-None-'),
  );
}
```

but when I submit the webform, the field is not submitted. What I mean by submitted, when I go to results of the webform, there does not exist a `medical_name` field, thus the field is not registered. This is an alter function, so yes I am creating `medical_name` field on alter. I checked the `formState->getValue` and it is there. So I am wondering what may be the problem? I want to add the field programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution I want, it is temporary:

In the UI, I created a select field with key `medical_area`
then with my alter function, it just override the webform and stored it there.

What I want:
Without having to create a select field in the UI, to be able to create a field through the alter function.